# The location is wrong after use transitionFromView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios-animations

I use `transitionFromView` switch two UIView ,But there is somethine wrong with it , When I transition the view to second UIView ,it work ok, then I transition the view back The error is happen(the location of first UIView is wrong)

**What happen?**

> ```
> self.primaryView.hidden = !self.primaryView.hidden
> self.secondaryView.hidden = !self.secondaryView.hidden
> println("\(self.primaryView)")
> UIView.transitionFromView(displayingPrimary ? self.primaryView : self.secondaryView,
>     toView: displayingPrimary ? self.secondaryView : self.primaryView,
>     duration: 1.0,
>     options: nil ) { (finish) -> Void in
>         if finish {
>             println("after:\(self.primaryView)")
>             self.displayingPrimary = !self.displayingPrimary;
>         }
>
> }
> ```

this is print info in console

```
<UIView: 0x79fe3c80; frame = (0 0; 399 349); hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x79fe3d10>>
after:<UIView: 0x79fe3c80; frame = (0 0; 399 349); hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x79fe3d10>>
<UIView: 0x79fe3c80; frame = (0 0; 399 349); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x79fe3d10>>
after:<UIView: 0x79fe3c80; frame = (-436 -328; 399 349); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x79fe3d10>>
```

Comment: I have resolve by [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219009/transitionfromview-removes-previous-view][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219009/transitionfromview-removes-previous-view